# Attach mouse movement to a div with Iframe inside

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mousemove, touchmove

In my `JS` code, I've added a `EventListener` on `mousemove` & `touchmove`, which makes it so that my `div` follows the `cursor`. *(as such)*

*CSS*:

```
  <style>
    body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 100vh;
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #8fc7f1, #7173f5);
overflow: hidden;
}
#my-div {
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
background-color: #ffffff;
position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

*HTML:*

```
<div id="my-div">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

*JAVASCRIPT:*

```
let myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");
//Detect touch device
function isTouchDevice() {
  try {
    //We try to create TouchEvent. It would fail for desktops and throw error
    document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

const move = (e) => {
  //Try, catch to avoid any errors for touch screens (Error thrown when user doesn't move his finger)
  try {
    //PageX and PageY return the position of client's cursor from top left of screen
    var x = !isTouchDevice() ? e.pageX : e.touches[0].pageX;
    var y = !isTouchDevice() ? e.pageY : e.touches[0].pageY;
  } catch (e) {}
  //set left and top of div based on mouse position
  myDiv.style.left = x - 150 + "px";
  myDiv.style.top = y - 120 + "px";
  // myDiv.style.opacity = 0;
  // console.log(myDiv.getBoundingClientRect())
};
//For mouse
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  move(e);
  console.log("Mouse")
});

//For touch
document.addEventListener("touchmove", (e) => {
  move(e);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/nbk4eo8m/)

What I'm trying to do is to add a `iframe` inside my `div` and the `div` should still follow the `cursor`, but when I add the `iframe` inside the `div`, then the `EventListener` stops working and my `div` stops following the cursor. I'm not sure what the issue is. *(as such)*

```
<div id="my-div">
    <iframe src="https://example.com/" width="300" height="250">
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE CODE WITH IFRAME](https://jsfiddle.net/2eytq4gL/)

Any help and suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: problem not with your js code problem is with your `iframe` tag please close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the closing `iframe` tag

```
<div id="my-div">
  <iframe src="https://example.com/" width="300" height="250"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the position of your div to relative and the position of your iframe to absolute.